# Swift Forin-where perform filter or skip (continue)?

Tags: swift, performance, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

I just gain a knowledge about Swift's forin-where, but it seems very lack of documents. So there's a question in my mind: Does it perform filter then loop or just loop with condition? given the below code

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in arr where i > 3 {
    print(i)
}
```

does the machine do like this:

```
for i in arr.filter { $0 > 3 }
```

or like this?

```
for i in arr {
    guard i > 3 else { continue } 
    print(i)
}
```

Should I use forin-where or just filter then foreach?

Comment: Like `for i in arr.lazy.filter { $0 > 3 }`

Comment: @user28434 If your loop content is short, you can even write like this `.forEach { print($0) }`

Comment: No, i mean in terms of applying filter `for … in … where` works just like `for … in … .lazy.filter`: get element -> check condition, pass it through. Without lazy it will first filter whole sequence and then loop over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the latter (iterate over all elements, execute the body only for 
elements satisfying the condition).

The for-statements takes an arbitrary *sequence,* not only arrays.
Filtering the sequence first would not only be inefficient (memory- and
time-wise), but also impossible for sequences producing “infinitely many” values, like in this example:

```
for x in 1... where x % 3 == 0 {
    print(x)
    if x > 10 { break }
}
```

Here `1...` is a “partial range” representing all integers greater than
or equal to one.

Comment: When iterate through large data, I usually filter first, then loop the result. Which way is more efficient in performance?

Comment: @Eddie: It depends. If you iterate only once then for-in-where should be faster because it does not create an intermediate array. If you need to iterate over the same filtered set multiple times then filtering first can be faster. – You'll have to measure and profile your use-case.